# Developer API key issue for AOL

Tags: aol

I am creating one new application using AOL login. For this I require developer api keys.I get the api keys for Facebook,twitter . But for aol.com , when I open dev.aol.com it redirects to www.aol.com always. Please anybody suggest me how to get APi kes for AOL . Why is this redirecting to home page ? Please reply

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the AOL Open Auth API has been discontinued.
http://www.programmableweb.com/api/aol-open-auth
http://www.programmableweb.com/api/aol-open-mail

All links that used to point to its documentation now point to the main aol.com website.

I also just called AOL and the technical support representative was unable to find any information at all on any developer APIs.

Sorry, looks like you're out of luck.