# Get client_id and secret from AOL

Tags: c#, aol

In my application, i want to authenticate (using OAuth) and fetch emails of AOL. I have all the logic for authorization and get access token too. But the problem is that when i'm opening dev.aol.com then it redirect me to www.aol.com instantly, So i'm confused about whats happening over here.
I just need to sign up to developer site and get client_id and client_secret that all, and rest i will do myself.

please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: dev.aol.com appears to be an old URL that is not used any more, the last post on their twitter feed was from 2012.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802877/developer-api-key-issue-for-aol

Comment: Then how can i get those Keys from AOL ?? Is there any way ?